# How to make plot a curve using JFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I have managed to plot a linear graph. The following is the code:

```
private JPanel createGraph() {

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        XYSeries series = new XYSeries("MyGraph");
        series.add(0, 1);
        series.add(1, 2);
        series.add(2, 5);
        series.add(7, 8);
        series.add(9, 10);


        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        dataset.addSeries(series);

        JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
                "XY Chart",
                "x-axis",
                "y-axis",
                dataset, 
                PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
                true,
                true,
                false
                );
        ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);


        panel.add(chartPanel);

        return panel;
    }
```

However, it is not a smooth curve, but straight lines. How can I make it smooth please?

Comment: Without seeing the graph itself I think is because is how it is supposed to be. If you want a curve you should add more points to the graph that eventually forms a curve.

Comment: My graph is something similar to this: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartXYSeriesDemo.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for [XYSplineRenderer](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYSplineRenderer.html)
You should be able to do

```
chart.getXYPlot().setRenderer(new XYSplineRenderer());
```

after your chart is constructed.